# Cant read php excel 2003 file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have this code that I use to read `Excel 2007` file.

```
 <?php 
 function load_table(){
    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("SampleData.xlsx");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5

    echo '<table class="table">' . "\n";
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
      echo '<tr>' . "\n";

      for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        echo '<td>';
        $first =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
        if($first[0] == '='){

            echo $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
        }
        else
            echo $first;

        echo '</td>' . "\n";

      }

      echo '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '</table>' . "\n"; 
}

?>
```

But I need to read an `Excel 2003` file. When I change the code I get error saying that:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2003' not found in ...

Change code:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2003');
```

Comment: Assuming that it's a valid SpreadsheetML file, then try using the `Excel2003XML` Reader, and read the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files); but if it's an `xlsx` file (`OfficeOpenXML` format) then you should be using the `Excel2007` Reader

Comment: @MarkBaker the xlsx files (2007) are working fine with that code. I need to read old.xls 2003 files.

Comment: If the file is a valid SpreadsheetML file, then use the `Excel2003XML` Reader.... but `.xls` is generally a BIFF-format file, and you should use the `Excel5` Reader for those

Comment: But why don't you let PHPExcel identify the format for you? It's generally not a good idea to assume that every file with an extension of `.xlsx` is one that can be read using the `Excel2007` Reader, or that every file with an extension of `.xls` is BIFF format, and can be read with the `Excel5` Reader.... a lot of the time, people create csv or html and simply give it an xls or xlsx extension

Comment: @MarkBaker And how would I let the tool decided? Sorry for the noobish, I'm doing this way because it's the way I could make it work ;p.  I just saw in other post of yours that sometimes `.xls` isn't a BIFF-format xls file.

Comment: Method #1: `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("SampleData.xlsx");`

Comment: Method #2: `$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("SampleData.xlsx"); $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("SampleData.xlsx");`

Comment: This is all documented in the documentation link that I provided above

Comment: @MarkBaker @MarkBaker It worked with the `Method #1`. But now I'm getting a lot of white space line, and also there are a lot of columns not being shown. But when I create a new `Excel 97-2003.xls` file, I got no problem showing its data.*Update:* I just opened the import file and `saved as` same format, now I get no problem with data show.Is it possible that the export system that gave me this file has some problem ? (it's from my college)

Comment: Not without seeing your file..... I can't guess what it contains

Comment: @MarkBaker Is there a way and possibility that you check my file? It worked once without the need of re-save the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use

```
 PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
```

or

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2003XML');
```

instead of

```
 PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
```

It's depends your xls file. You can read more details [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/01-File-Formats.md#excel2003xml) PHPExcel Docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
```

Make `phpexcel` identify what type of your file.